# I can't decompress PDF without invalidating it's signature

Tags: pdf, adobe

I'm learning how to spoof PDFs and the next step is being able to decompress a signed PDF in order to edit its raw/source material.  The problem I run into is after a signing a PDF the signature is valid, but the process of decompressing the file ends up invalidating the signature followed by the error

```
Error during signature verification.  

Signature contains incorrect, unrecognized, corrupted or suspicious data.
Support Information: SigDict /Contents illegal data
```

The two decompression methods I've used are [QPDF](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net), and [pdfyeah](https://www.pdfyeah.com/decompress-pdf/), and both of them ended up having the same problem.

The QPDF command I used was  `qpdf  --qdf  original.pdf  unpacked.pdf`, I'm sure sure if there are different options/flags that I could use to achieve decompression of the file without invalidating the signature.

If anybody knows a way to decompress without invalidating signatures please let me know! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm sure sure if there are different options/flags that I could use to achieve decompression of the file without invalidating the signature.
>
> If anybody knows a way to decompress without invalidating signatures please let me know!

That is impossible.

A digital signature integrated in a PDF (at least an interoperable one) signs all the **bytes** of that file (except the placeholder containing the signature itself). Decompressing obviously changes those bytes, so the signature is invalidated.

Consequentially, you can also not spoof those bytes without invalidating the signature.

What you can try, though, is

- change content in the placeholder (which can be larger than the signature and be filled with zeros) or
- add content at the end as an incremental update.

Also you can try techniques as presented on the [PDF Insecurity](https://www.pdf-insecurity.org/signature/signature.html) site. Current viewer versions *should* notice these techniques but probably they don't....